# Unable to compile C code (Developer Tools, OS X)

Tags: c, macos, gcc, kernel, clang

I wasn't really sure what to put as the title, but I'll attempt to explain my problem as best as I can.

I'm attempting to follow James Molloy's kernel development tutorials, using OS X as my development operating system. I successfully got the developer tools installed and am able to compile C programs, as well as use NASM, but now my problem lies here:

```
 main.c 4:5 error: first parameter of 'main' (argument count) must be of type 'int'
```

Here's the code (yes, it's copied and pasted and from the first tutorial):

```
// main.c -- Defines the C-code kernel entry point, calls initialisation routines.
//           Made for JamesM's tutorials <www.jamesmolloy.co.uk>

int main(struct multiboot *mboot_ptr)
{
// All our initialisation calls will go in here.
return 0xDEADBABA;
}
```

Unfortunately, after a bit of googling (but perhaps I'm just googling the wrong thing), I haven't found a solution. The makefile (also copied and pasted) is this:

```
Makefile for JamesM's kernel tutorials.
The C and C++ rules are already setup by default.
The only one that needs changing is the assembler 
rule, as we use nasm instead of GNU as.

SOURCES=boot.o main.o

CFLAGS=-Wall -fstrength-reduce -nostdlib -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector
LDFLAGS=-Tlink.ld
ASFLAGS=-felf

all: $(SOURCES) link

clean:
    -rm *.o kernel

link:
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o kernel $(SOURCES)

.s.o:
    nasm $(ASFLAGS) $<
```

If someone could kindly point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

I have a feeling it might be something that I'm misunderstanding with Clang, but I really don't know if so. Also, if using OS X as a kernel developing platform is not advised (I'd really like to use it) then could you please point me in the right direction to a suitable platform for OS development?

Comment: Provide a link to these tutorials.

Comment: http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html
Here you go.

Comment: And you are sure his tutorial is supported under OSX?

Comment: I had the thought that, due to him saying "I'm assuming you're using a *nix system with the GNU toolchain", it would work. Was I wrong in thinking so?

Comment: Not sure; but you would need to verify before even trying.

Comment: I'm beginning to think not, I have tried pretty much everything that I can (but I'm not ruling anything out either). The main thing that puzzles me is this, though: `first parameter of 'main' (argument count) must be of type 'int'`.

Comment: Well obviously the compiler has seen the declaration for `int main(int argc, const char **argv)` and thinks you mean that.  This is a fundamental error as kernel code shouldn't go anywhere near `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: the warning says it. Your signature of main does not match the C standard that requires main to be `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char**)`

Comment: How am I able to prevent this? I'm not including <stdio.h> in the file. Is there a way to prevent `clang` from thinking this? Thank you for your help, by the way.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: I see your point, but unless I am really overlooking something, I do not understand why this does not work.

Comment: When you are compiling for a freestanding environment (kernel etc...) instead of a hosted environment (c library with start files etc...) you can use `-ffreestanding` or at least `-nostdlib` `-nostdinc` `-nostartfiles`  With -ffreestanding you can create a `_start()` that calls main() with the appropriate `struct multiboot *mboot_ptr`, but more likely you should just not call it `main()`

Answer (score 1):

I found this page called "James Molloy's Tutorial Known Bugs"  http://wiki.osdev.org/James_Molloy%27s_Tutorial_Known_Bugs and one remark is: *This isn't a regular* `main` *function: The name* `main` *is actually a special case in C and it would be inadvisable to call it that. You should call it something like* `kernel_main` *instead.*